# Call an input list in a function from another function

Tags: python-3.x, list, algorithm, function

this time I'm trying to figure out how can i call a function named listInput that the user will input numbers separated by commas and convert its into a list, the thing is i want instead this list is created call this function in another function that takes as args a list, how can i do it? Thanks for the answers.

```
def divisibleBy(lista,n):
    return [x for x in lista if x % n == 0]

def inputList():
    cad = input("Insert a number")
    user_cad = cad.split(",")
    for i in range(len(user_cad)):
        user_cad[i] = int(user_cad[i])
    return user_cad

print(divisibleBy(inputList(),4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: Just noticed why lol, fixed code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).